# Issue with mvcContrib fluent route testing in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, fluent, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have an issue with testing routes using the MVCContrib Fluent route testing. The test fails yet the application recognises the routes.

Let me explain....

I have the following routes in my register (shown in order)

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "PurchaseUnitsPaged",
                "PurchaseUnits/Page{page}",
                new { controller = "PurchaseUnits", action = "Index", page = 1 },
                new { page = @"\d+" }
                );


routes.MapRoute(
                "PurchaseUnit",
                "PurchaseUnits/{unitname}",
                new { controller = "PurchaseUnits", action = "Show" }
            );
```

The routing pipeline correctly sends requests to **Index** for route 1 and **Show** for route 2.

However when I test the routing using the MVCContrib fluent classes I get a test fail for route 1.

The test is:

```
"~/PurchaseUnits/Page{page}".ShouldMapTo<PurchaseUnitsController>(x=> x.Index(1));
```

The test fails because the expectation is **Index** but the actual is **Show**.

Any ideas as to why the fluent classes aren't identifying the correct routing yet the mvc routing works in the actual application? Or failing that any suggestions about how I can tweak my test or routes to allow me to fully test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test should be:

```
"~/PurchaseUnits/Page1".ShouldMapTo<PurchaseUnitsController>(x=> x.Index(1));
```

The url is `~/PurchaseUnits/Page1` and not `~/PurchaseUnits/Page{page}`.

Comment: Cheers for the answer Darin, that works.

I'm slightly confused though because I test the second route mentioned in the question by using the following test

"~/PurchaseUnits/{unitname}".Route().ShouldMapTo<PurchaseUnitsController>(x => x.Show("{unitname}"));

Comment: That's because "{unitname}" matches "{unitname}".  If your original test was "~/PurchaseUnits/Page{page}".ShouldMapTo<PurchaseUnitsController>(x=> x.Index("{page}")); it (edit: WOULD NOT) have worked, but apparently Index takes an int  while Show takes a string. Actually, looking at your code closer, "~/PurchaseUnits/Page{page}" does not match your first route, as the value "{page}" is not matched by "\d+", and instead would fall down to the next route PurchaseUnitsController.Show("Page{page}").